# Unable to install Wordpress plugins on Heroku

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku, zlib, php-extension

I installed Heroku on Wordpress by using the guidelines from https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku. The system works fine. Only when I try to install plugins I receive the error message

`Abort class-pclzip.php : Missing zlib extensions`.

The error message is clear, zlib missing. I was just wondering if anyone of you had the same issue and can provide some best practices how to solve the problem?

Comment: compile PHP --with-zlib

Comment: The repository mentioned above uses the deprecated PHP buildpack for Heroku. I was looking for a solution where I don't have to fork the buildpack and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that heroku does not allow you to create files and you have to extract plugins and themes locally inside their folders respectively and push your changes back to your heroku repository. From the [wordpress-heroku documentation](https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku#usage):

> Because a file cannot be written to Heroku's file system, updating and
>   installing plugins or themes should be done locally and then pushed to
>   Heroku.

Comment: Thanks, thought there would be a way that  plugins would be installed into the database.

Comment: You can write files, but they'll be gone the next time you push obviously (or whenever a dyno restarts), see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not allow you to modify files. You cannot use the backend of Wordpress to do those things if the site is hosted on Heroku. You have to install locally and then deploy. There is a good tutorial here:

http://wptutorialguide.com/wordpress-on-heroku/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).